# Aurelia, Docker, Nginx, AWS Elastic Beanstalk Showing 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, aurelia, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've deployed an Aurelia application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk via AWS ECR and have run into some difficulty. The docker container, when run locally, works perfectly (see below for Dockerfile).

```
FROM nginx:1.15.8-alpine

COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

The deployment works quite well, however when I navigate to the AWS provided endpoint `http://docker-tester.***.elasticbeanstalk.com/` I get `502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.12.1`.

I can't figure out what might be the issue. The docker container in question is a simple Hello World example created via the `au new` command; it's nothing fancy at all.

Below is my Dockerrun.aws.json file

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "***.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/tester:latest",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "8080"
    }
  ],
  "Logging": "/var/log/nginx"
}
```

My Elastic Beanstalk configuration is rather small with an EC2 instance type of `t2.micro`. I'm using the free tier as an opportunity to learn.

I greatly appreciate any help, or links to some reading that may point in the right direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has nothing to do with your aurelia application. You are missing `EXPOSE` statement (which is mandatory) in your `Dockerfile`. You can change it like this.

```
FROM nginx:1.15.8-alpine

EXPOSE 80

COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

If you try to run it without `EXPOSE`, you will get an error

```
ERROR: ValidationError - The Dockerfile must list ports to expose on the Docker container. Specify at least one port, and then try again.
```

You should test your application before pushing it to ElasticBeanstalk

install `eb cli` (assuming that you have `pip`, if not then you need to install it as well)

```
pip install awsebcli --upgrade --user
```

then initialize local repository for deployment

```
eb init -p docker <application-name>
```

and you can test it

```
eb local run --port <port-number>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've updated the `Dockerfile`, re-created the image and followed your steps to install `aws eb cli`. This all seems fine, however when executing `eb local run --port 80`, I receive the error `docker: invalid reference format.` Any suggestions?

Comment: The deploy to Elastic Beanstalk works perfectly by the way. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JPDamstra I have tried your setup, only changed repository, and it worked. Maybe there is a problem with ECR. Try to use some public image (i.e `matusdubrava/ebtest:v1`  as a name of the image `"Name": "matusdubrava/ebtest:v1"`) and see if it works or not.